# C# Line chart axis points

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts

I have an application that uses a line chart. Every second my application reads a value and its recording time from database and add that value and its recording time to a line chart. Value is in Y axis and record time is in X axis.

My line chart's x points increase one by one every seconds. I want line chart have more x points with no Y values when it is first created (about 60 points of seconds when it is first created). How can i do that?

Note : recording time is DateTime. It shows hours minutes and seconds

Comment: Can you show us a snippet of code? Whats wrong with populating the data collection that you bind to the Chart with 60 empty or zero values?

Comment: `this.chartMonitor.Series["1.1 Proses"].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), value);`

Comment: Why not simnply add the 60 points at the beginning???

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the minimum and maximum value for the X axis of your chart before adding points to it.

Assuming your chart has index CHART_INDEX, and that the start and end times are of type `DateTime`, do this:

```
var xAxis = yourChart.ChartAreas[CHART_INDEX].AxisX;
xAxis.Minimum = myStartTime.ToOADate();
xAxis.Maximum = myEndTime.ToOADate();
```

Comment: I used this but i cant see any value `DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
chartMonitor.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = time.ToOADate();
time.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0));
chartMonitor.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = time.ToOADate();`

Comment: Well this works for me in my graphs - it's the right way to do it. Are the points you are adding definitely within the start and end times?

Comment: I corrected my code. Now parent form of its parent form throw OverflowException